# How to create preferences in Android?

Tags: android, mobile, sharedpreferences

I have a problem with android settings. I want to create settings for changing the background color of an activity. What do I have to do?

I have layout:

```
public class MyApp extends PreferenceActivity{


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

public void display(View view) 
{
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Display.class);

    startActivity(intent);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{

    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}


public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem item)
{

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.menu_about:
        Intent menu_about = new Intent(this, About.class);
         startActivity(menu_about);
        return true;

    case R.id.menu_copyright:
        Intent menu_copyright = new Intent(this, Copyright.class);
        startActivity(menu_copyright);

        return true;

    case R.id.menu_settings:

        // ACTIVITY OF SETTINGS
        return true;

    case R.id.menu_exit:

        finish();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
};
```

}

I want preference like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2qA5.png

Now, did You understend me?

Comment: What ? can't get you.

Comment: I try create custom settings to change background color, but I don't know how I should doing.

Comment: Do you want to allow a user to edit them and persist these changes in shared preferences? Are you questioning how to show/store these preferences, or how to use them? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You use setTheme() before setContentView() in your onCreate() method.

Comment: I want to allow user change color of background. But i can't create setting activity.

Comment: @gilu66 when do you want the user to change the background color  ?

Comment: I want, that user can change color in settings of my app. For example : button MENU\Settings\change color and user can choose one of five color.

Comment: Your answer likes good, but i check it evening. Thanks

Comment: @Android Developer Unfortunatly doesn't its works.

Answer (score 1):

Create SharedPreferences this way

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
 editor.putString("PrefName", VALUE);
 editor.commit();
```

Get its values this way

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
 String s = settings.getString("PrefName", ""));
```

The last statement means you are looking for the value of "PrefName" and setting "" if nothing is found.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

**menu.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item    
        android:id="@+id/settings"    
        android:title="Settings"    
       >
        <menu>
             <item android:id="@+id/red"
                  android:title="Red" />

            <item android:id="@+id/Blue"

                  android:title="Blue" />

    </menu>  
   </item>  

     </menu>
```

**AndroidMenusActivity.java**

```
public class AndroidMenusActivity extends Activity {
   LinearLayout li;
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            li= findViewById(R.id.layoutid);
        }



  @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
            menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
            return true;
        }


  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.red:
              li.setBackgroundColor("#ff0000");
            break;

        case R.id.blue:
              li.setBackgroundColor("#0000ff");
        break;

        }
    }
```

}

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean Change the activity background over XML file?

> android:background="@android:color/xxxxx"

Pick one of listed color.